# User defined menu shortcut doesn't work with Safari

Tags: shortcut-menu

I want to add a shortcut to "refresh" the web page in Safari (5.0.2).
I added a shortcut definition in the System Preferences.

> [image]

I disabled the usage of the Fonction keys by the System.
I have "F5" shown next to "Reload Page" menu item. But, this does not work.

What went wrong ?

Comment: I did the same thing, in an attempt to reproduce the problem and… i have the same issue.

Comment: @Martin : If you manage to have the Menu dropped (just by a click on the menu name "View"), and then hit the F5 key, it works... Nice bug then. Thanks for you testings.

Comment: I know you disabled Fn keys. But even if you press Fn + F5 it still doesn't work? If so You guys should report that bug to apple: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: This is odd, I have a shortcut to open the page with Chrome (Shift-Cmd-C) in the Develop menu, and the same thing happens. The command doesn’t work unless: either I have Chrome already open already OR I click on the menu and then hit the shortcut (with the menu open).

Answer (score 2):

As other commenters have said, it works once the menu has been shown at least once. Safari seems to build its menus differently from other apps, and seems to do it dynamically when you open them the first time. Hence, the system has no way to know that such a Refresh menu item exists unless you've tried opening the menu once.