# User-defined shortcut doesn't work properly

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, shortcut

I want to add a shortcut to "Advanced Search" option in the Zotero reference manager but user-defined shortcut doesn't work unless I click the edit button first. Here, you can see shortcut is assigned and it works if I hit the shortcut after I click the edit button like in the picture. Any workaround to this?

[image]

There is a similar problem [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/user-defined-menu-shortcut-doesnt-work-with-safari) but no solution.

Comment: Have you tried using a less-common shortcut? Cmd/s is Save in pretty much all apps.

Comment: Yes but that's also not working unless I click the edit button.